# Python 3- Modules

Tags: python-3.x, module

```
import itertools
import operator
def performIterator(tuplevalues):
    mainlist=[]
    list1=[]
    tuple1len = len(tuplevalues[0])
    count = 0
    for i in itertools.cycle(tuplevalues[0]):
        if count>tuple1len-1:
            break
        else:
            list1.append(i)
            count +=1
    tuple1 = tuple(list1)
    mainlist.append(tuple1[0:4])
    tuple2 = tuplevalues[1]
    mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.repeat(tuple2[0],4)))
    tuple3=tuplevalues[2]
    mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.accumulate(tuple3)))
    tuple4=tuplevalues[3]
    chainedtuple=tuple(itertools.chain(tuple1,tuple2,tuple3,tuple4))
    mainlist.append(chainedtuple)   
    mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x%2 == 0,chainedtuple)))
    return tuple(mainlist) 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    length = int(input().strip())

    qw1 = []
    for i in range(4):
        qw2 = []
        for _ in range(length):
          qw2_item = int(input().strip())
          qw2.append(qw2_item)
        qw1.append(tuple(qw2))
    tupb = tuple(qw1)

    q = performIterator(tupb)
    print(q)
```

Input: 5
46
34
18
76
27
45
374
981
789
168
43
97
615
9
65
782
367
481
816
46

Required Output: ((46, 34, 18, 76), (45, 45, 45, 45, 45), (43, 140, 755, 764, 829), (46, 34, 18, 76, 27, 45, 374, 981, 789, 168, 43, 97, 615, 9, 65, 782, 367, 481, 816, 46), (27, 45, 981, 789, 43, 97, 615, 9, 65, 367, 481))

Output i get:

> > ((46, 34, 18, 76), (45, 45, 45, 45), (43, 140, 755, 764, 829), (46, 34, 18, 76, 27, 45, 374, 981, 789, 168, 43, 97, 615, 9, 65, 782, 367, 481, 816, 46), (27, 45, 981, 789, 43, 97, 615, 9, 65, 367, 481))

Help me solve this

Comment: What is it you are trying to 'Solve"  What isn't working?  This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
    mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.repeat(tuple2[0],4)))
```

to

```
    mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.repeat(tuple2[0],5)))
```

you get the *Required Output*.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify this line

```
mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.repeat(tuple2[0],4)))
```

into this

```
mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.repeat(tuple2[0],len(tuple2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Do below it will work

```
mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.repeat(tuple2[0],length)))
```

Comment: when providing an answer please try to explain the solution

Answer (score 0):

what I feel is that you should add second parameter in the function of

itertools.repeat(value_in_tuple_to_be_repeated) as len(tuplevalues[1]),

where tuplevalues[1] is your tuple object. value in tuple to be repeated-tuple2[0]

```
mainlist.append(tuple(itertools.repeat(tuple2[0],len(tuplevalues[1]))))
```